# How to restore large size backup in sql server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have 40 GB .bak file from `SQL 2008 R2`.When I tried restore to `SQL 2012` I get this error

> " System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: CREATE DATABASE or ALTER DATABASE
>   failed because the resulting cumulative database size would exceed
>   your licensed limit of 10240 MB (10GB) per database.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Express.Smo). "

Comment: are you using an express edition?

Comment: @Nithesh I am using this version http://t1307.hizliresim.com/1c/m/qh6gc.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using SQL Servere 2008 R2 `Express` edition the `maximum size of one DB is 10 GB`

Maximum database size  database as follows in express editions,

```
 SQL Server 2012   10GB
 SQL Server 2008 R2 10GB
 SQL Server Express 2008 4GB
```

Comment: 2012  also allows only `10GB` for express version

Comment: Is there any way for restore ? Query ?

Comment: i think you need a full version for such a large DB.

Comment: Which version ? Full express version ?

Comment: SQL Server Full version not the express version.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33746/discussion-between-nithesh-and-mehmet-akyel)